# TFS: Build solution containing both .NET 6 and Full Framework apps

Tags: .net, tfs, .net-6.0

We are in the process of migrating a web app from .NET 4.8 to .NET 6. While we're in the migration process, we have the old app and the new app both stored in the same solution. We want to be able to build and deploy both apps.

After adding the .NET 6 app, when I try to build the entire solution, (either using the .NET Core steps or using the Visual Studio Build steps), I get the following error even though I have a NuGet Restore step immediately prior to the build step:

`This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them`

Has anyone seen this issue? How did you successfully build your solutions that contain both frameworks?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you verify that the packages are indeed downloading and that the projects that need them are pointing at that location?

Comment: yes, we have a common nuget feed that we use for all of our builds. Prior to adding the .NET 6 app, the Visual Studio Build step ran successfully.

Comment: Does the .NET 48 app still use the old csproj format? If so, you cannot build that with `dotnet` cli.

Comment: It does use the old csproj format.

Comment: Is it possible to set up the build to NOT build the entire solution? Like, I could have 2 separate builds - one that targets the NET4.8 app and another that targets the NET6 app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by adding multiple Build Configurations and then having multiple build steps (one for each build config.)

### In Visual Studio

In my solution, I created a build configuration that builds all of the projects tied to my full framework app called "ReleaseLegacy", and another config that builds all the projects tied to my .NET 6 app called "ReleaseNET6".

### In TFS

I added my two build configurations as variables for my build.

[image]

To build to full framework app, I used the Visual Studio Build step, targeting the entire solution, but using the "ReleaseLegacy" build configuration.

[image]

To build the .NET 6 app, I used the .NET Core `build` step, targeting the entire solution, but using the "ReleaseNET6" build configuration.

[image]

Prior to both of the build steps, I also had to add the .NET Core `restore` step as well as the legacy NuGet Restore step. I'm not 100% sure *why* but the .NET Core step was required to get the full framework build step to succeed.

[image]

Similar to the build steps, I had to add separate test steps for the full framework apps compared to the .NET 6 apps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Another option besides creating separate build configurations could be to separate your full framework apps into a separate directory from your .NET 6 apps, then use the .NET Core build steps to run `dotnet msbuild` as a custom command and target specific directories